# Windows RDP Client Version

Tags: rdp

Does anyone know how to tell which RDP version windows is running with?

Comment: It would be nice if you didn't ask this on SU AND SF (http://superuser.com/questions/118458/rdp-version-number) so all the replies can be consolidated in one place. This is more of an SU question anyways. (Yes, I am aware I'm being just as bad by double-posting this comment on SU and SF.)

Comment: I didn't know they were so interconnected, or that someone would really notice or care - I'll keep that in mind next time.  Thanks :)

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

The following are the default versions shipped.  You can install newer clients (like RDP 7.0 in Windows XP SP3) so it would be dependent on your environment as to whether these have been installed.  I presume they would show up as updates in Add/Remove programs.

RDP 5.0

- Windows 2000 server

RDP 5.1

- Windows XP Professional

RDP 5.2

- Windows Server 2003

RDP 6.0

- Windows Vista
- Windows XP SP2
- Winows Server 2003 SP1 and SP2
- Windows XP Professional x64

RDP 6.1

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Vista SP1
- Windows XP SP3
- Windows XP SP2 (if update KB952155 is installed)

RDP 6.2

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

When you have the RDP window open, left click on the top left corner. In the menu that opens, click "About".

Answer (score 0):

The client is mstsc.exe; search for it (it'll be in Windows/system32, probably) right click on it, and go to the version tab.

@Zoredache: Depends on which version of Windows you're running.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean the 'Details' Tab?